# Django Authentication fails

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I try to create the login page for my application but I can't authenticate the user no matter what I try for a week now.

Here is my code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.db import IntegrityError
from .models import User

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "login.html", {"message": f"{user}"})
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))
    else:
        return render(request, "login.html")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import index, login_view, register

urlpatterns = [
    path("", index, name="index"),
    path("login", login_view, name="login"),
    path("register", register, name="register")
]
```

login.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="fluid-container">
    <h3 id="header">Login</h3>
    {% if message %}
        <h4>{{ message }}</h4>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post" class="form" action="{% url 'login' %}">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register one here.</a></p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The user is always None, but the username and password come back correct.

Comment: how does user look in database, also why do you override AbstractUser if you are not doing any changes

Comment: @iklinac What do you mean how does the user look?
Register function is working, that's why I didn't mention it and the fields are the same as login, username and password.
I intend to modify the User class later, but I have to be able to login first.

Comment: how does your user row look in database, particularly interested in password

Comment: Well you opened my eyes.. I just used "User.objects.create_user(username, password)" in register and it messed it?
Not sure why though

Changing it to "User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)" fixes the issue.